# JavaScript - Adding an array to prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, instance

I have spent a lot of time researching JavaScript's prototype chain, different models for inheritance and object oriented structures in JavaScript. There is still one thing that puzzles me and that I can not seem to find a straight answer to. Please allow me to demonstrate using the following code example.

```
function Obj(){}
Obj.prototype.numbers = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"];
Obj.prototype.color = "GREEN";

var test1 = new Obj();
var test2 = new Obj();

test1.numbers[0] = "ZERO";
test1.color = "BLUE";

console.log(test1.numbers + " | " + test2.numbers); //ZERO, TWO, THREE | ZERO, TWO, THREE
console.log(test1.color + " | " + test2.color); //BLUE | GREEN
```

Can anyone explain why only array properties seem to be shared among instances and not other types?

Comment: You're adding an array as a prototype, so that array is shared across instances, that's how prototypes work when using values that are passed as a (value containing a) reference.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure there's a good QA which could be used for closing *and* would be clear. I just don't find it :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230085/javascript-prototype-property-not-working-as-expected-with-array-and-object-fiel

Comment: It is the difference between deep and shallow copying.

Comment: If you do `test1.numbers = ['another','array']`, you'll see that test1 and test2 hold two different arrays. That's the difference between changing the value of a property and changing the value of an item of the array.

Comment: @TravisJ: No, it's the difference between setting the value of a property and changing the *state* of what that property refers to. Nothing to do with copying, and certainly not deep copying.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying. Also, I apologize for the duplicate, I failed to find that post when searching. @T.J.Crowder So if I understand you correctly, when I'm doing `test1.color = "BLUE";` the `color` property no longer points to the one defined on the prototype but rather becomes part of the instantiated object `test1`?